# Show that if a proper function has a subgradient everywhere in its convex domain, then it's convex.

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow (-\infty,\infty]$ be proper. If $\operatorname{dom} f$ is convex and $\operatorname{dom} \partial f=\operatorname{dom} f$, show that $f$ is convex. I wonder what is the angle to prove such a statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is straightforward; if we can write
$f(x) = \sup_{h \in H} h(x)$ where each $h \in H$ is convex, then $f$ is convex.

Let $H = \{ y \mapsto f(x)+g^T(y-x) | x \in \operatorname{dom}f, g \in \partial f(x) \}$.

Comment: The set of functions in $H$ is convex, only cause $\partial f$ and $ dom f$ is convex right?

Comment: @lone_wolf It is not relevant. What matters is that it is the pointwise $\sup$ of a collection of convex functions, hence convex.

Comment: Yes, I understand that the supremum of convex functions is convex. But my doubt is,if $\partial f$ is not convex,  will it then be convex only within the convex subset of $\partial f$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $H$ be a family of linear functions using the following definition,
$$
H=\{x\rightarrow f(z)+g^T(x-z)|z\in \operatorname{dom} f, g\in\partial f(z)\}
$$
From the definition of subgradients, we know that $\forall h\in H$,
$$
f(x)\ge h(x)
$$
so that
$$
f(x) \ge \underset{h\in H}\sup h(x)
$$
On the other hand, we can always let $z=x$, then any $h\in H$ will satisfy
$$
h(x)=f(x)\ge f(x)
$$
so that
$$
\underset{h\in H}\sup h(x) \ge f(x)
$$
Hence $f(x)=\underset{h\in H}\sup h(x)$ is convex as the supremum of a family of linear functions.